# Mapbox: Center map after popup closes

Tags: mapbox

I have a mapbox project that I need to be able to re-center the map when a popup closes. Right now, clicking a marker will pan the map and after the user closes the popup they are left with the map panned over to the new location. I simply need the map to recenter to the original location I set as my map center.

I've not found a method using the mapbox api so I don't have any code to start. I'm more looking for someone who might have experience with such a configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/) is built on top of leaflet you can use the [Leaflet API](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

You can listen for [popupclose](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-popupclose) events. Then you can call `map.setView()` and center the map at the original position.

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pe5xU/284/)